# finding ratio of an array of intergers between 2 integers l and r. in javascript

Tags: javascript

You are given an array of integers a and two integers l and r. You task is to calculate a boolean array b, where b[i] = true if there exists an integer x, such that a[i] = (i + 1) * x and l ≤ x ≤ r. Otherwise, b[i] should be set to false.

```js
function boundedRatio(a, l, r) {
  let b = []
  for (let i = l; i <= r; i++) {
    //  
    for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      let result = (j + 1) * i

      if ((j + 1) * i === a[j] && l <= i <= r) {
        b.push(true)
      } else {
        b.push(false)
      }

    }
  }

  return b

  boundedRatio([8, 5, 6, 16, 5], 1, 3)
  // [false, false, true, false, true]
```

Comment: You're missing the ending `}` of the function.

Comment: You're pushing onto `b` every time through the inner loop. You should only push onto it once for each element of `a`.

Comment: You don't need `&& l <= i <= r` since the `for` loop guarantees that.

Answer (score 2):

Your main loop should be over the array `a`. For each of them, you need a loop over `l` through `r`. In that loop you should just set a variable to inidcate whether the bounded value is found. Once you find it you can break out of the loop. Then you push that onto the result.

The main loop and push can be combine with `map()`.

```js
function boundedRatio(a, l, r) {
  let b = a.map((el, i) => {
    let bounded = false;
    for (let x = l; x <= r; x++) {
      if ((i + 1) * x == el) {
        bounded = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return bounded;
  })

  return b;
}

console.log(boundedRatio([8, 5, 6, 16, 5], 1, 3));
```

Here's how it looks with a `for` loop instead of `map()`.

```js
function boundedRatio(a, l, r) {
  let b = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let bounded = false;
    for (let x = l; x <= r; x++) {
      if ((i + 1) * x == a[i]) {
        bounded = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    b.push(bounded);
  }

  return b;
}

console.log(boundedRatio([8, 5, 6, 16, 5], 1, 3));
```

Comment: thank you so much. Could you also show me what it would look like without using map to combine the main loop and the push. so that i may understand it better?

Comment: I've added a version with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can write down this code in C# also like that.

```
bool[] solution(int[] numbers, int left, int right) {
bool [] result=new bool[numbers.Length];
for(int i =0; i < numbers.Length; i++ )
{
    bool bounded = false;
    for(int x = left; x <= right; x++)
    {
        if((i+1)*x == numbers[i])
        {
            bounded= true;
            break;
        }
    }
    result[i] = bounded;
}
return result;
```

}